# Maximization in l1 norm

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, absolute-value, nonlinear-optimization

I have formulated a problem as follows.

$${max \sum_{i=1}^l\sum_{k=1}^m|\sum_{j=1}^nw_{j}*(a_{ij}-b_{kj}+r_{kij}*x_{kij})|}$$
$$s.t.w_{j}*|a_{ij}-b_{kj}+r_{kij}*x_{kij}|\leq w_{j}*|a_{ij}-b_{tj}+r_{tij}*x_{tij}|$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^l\sum_{k=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n x_{kij}\leq m$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^nw_{j}=1$$
$$w_{j}\geq0 \forall j$$
$$x_{kij}\in \{0,1\} \forall k,i,j$$

$a_{ij}, b_{kj},r_{kij}$ values are constant. $x_{kij}$ is a binary variable, $w_{j}$ is a continuous variable.

As far as I know, maximizing absolute values is not an easy task. I have thought I could try to minimize the objective function by multiplying it by (-). But not quite sure if that would work. Would it be possible to solve this problem? I am open for recommendations.

Would using any other p norm make more sense to solve this problem?

Comment: Maximizing l1 norm cannot be convexified by simple tricks like changing the objective sign etc., especially since you also have constraints with absolute value on the "wrong" side of the inequality. So you are right, it is not an easy task. You could rewrite it as a mixed-integer problem and use a MIP solver. Maximizing other p-norms is similarly hard.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Could you elobarate the what you mean by the wrong side of the inequality? Also, I would really appreciate if you could provide any books/references about MIP. @MichalAdamaszek

Comment: I mean $t\geq |x|$ is convex but $t\leq |x|$ is not. If you want to formulate exact absolute value or L1 norm as a MIP you can start at https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/mio.html#exact-absolute-value